# Performance of Tensorflow vs Tensorflow Lite

Tags: python, tensorflow, performance-testing, tensorflow-lite

Is there a performance loss when converting TensorFlow models to the TensorFlow Lite format?
Because I got these results from different edge-devices:

[image: Performance Results - SSD MobileNet V2]

Does it make sense that the Nvidia Jetson has a higher accuracy with the TensorFlow model (TensorRT optimized) when comparing it to the Raspberry one which is a TensorFlow Lite model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, there is a performance loss, but not such a significant one, more precisely around 3% in accuracy for instance in some certain models, but you have to test it on your own to check the accuracy.

Models which are subjected to TensorRT or TensorFlow-Lite do not go through the same exact conversion steps(otherwise they would be the same). Therefore, it is evident that a difference is noticeable.

To conclude: The gain in speed as compared to the performance loss(max 3%) is much more important. For each and every assumption tests should be employed.

This article is also a good read: https://www.hackster.io/news/benchmarking-tensorflow-and-tensorflow-lite-on-the-raspberry-pi-43f51b796796

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer :)
Do you have any articles which show a performance loss, like you said, when converting TensorFlow models to TensorFlow Lite?

Comment: In the article you mentioned are just the timing benchmarks listed. I am searching for articles about the accuracy loss when converting from TensorFlow to TensorFlow Lite. Have you any other literature related to this?

Comment: Sure scch-sims! Have a look here: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quant