# Low Accuracy in TensorFlow

Tags: android, flutter, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I ve download this files from the official docs

https://github.com/tensorflow/flutter-tflite/tree/main/example/audio_classification

The thing is that i have very low accuracy in some data.
For example cat sounds have big accuracy like 80%-90% but when i try other sounds it does not detect them , not even like 10%.

I dont think that the configure is false, i mean is the official page right?

So whats the problem?

Does Yamnet have low accuracy in some data and more accuracy in others?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am confused by this question. What other sounds? Are they in the dataset that the model was trained on? https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/yamnet Audio-wise how does your test audio compare against the training set. Be aware that StackOverflow is for specific programming questions, and there many free online resources for understanding the details of Machine Learning.

Comment: Yes the sounds are in the dataset. I ask here because many ppl said in forums that if its wrong configured then it will give false responses. Thats why i post the github url in order to see someone who knows about tensorflow lite - yamnet if it is something false or not .Its a ready model so i dont think the courses is the problem..

Comment: Curious how you did testing. If you used the dataset did you play it back using device microphone or feed it in as a file. That said these are 'example' models so the conversion from full Tensorflow to TF Lite may have affected accuracy. Related: [Why don't people always use TensorFlow Lite](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/17151/19758) and [Performance of Tensorflow vs Tensorflow Lite](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61120264/295004) You can build your own Yamnet model for more accuracy but probably with a trade-off of fewer features/performance/size.

Comment: Yiep i used my smartphone as a source of sound output and my laptop with a simulator as an input. I enable android simulator microphone also to be sure . I can train some models but im  afraid it wont be so accurate as yamnet so im afraid to risk it . I found google teachable machine but i suppose yamnet is more "tested model" than do it from scratch.In the forum they are saying about 3% loss but mine is far more , i think is like 90% - 100% or something like that . Also what do you mean by "example" models? Thank you again for the fast response :)

Comment: You may want to try the other way, audio-into-smartphone and see how that is. The best check would be to feed in the training audio by file. If direct file works, then it is probably a hw/sw issue between PC and phone or even the emulator (audio distortion?). Regardless what I mean by "example" models is that they were built as a sample to show off the power of ML with unknown regression testing (as you may have discovered) or what tradeoffs were made to provide the prebuilt models. As noted in the docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/audio_classification/overview#limitations

Comment: Still got low accuracy , iv tried and download in docker so i run there yamnet model .Still its accuracy is low.. i wanna try it in some vehicles so i guess it can not seperate the engine sound 100% .